# Variables inside .Offset Method

Tags: excel, vba

I've noticed some weird behavior using variables inside the offset method.

Here's my code

```
Dim r As Integer 
r=1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0 + (r = 1)).Select
```

the first select seems to work as expected, it selects the cell one column to the right. 
However, the second actually selects the cell one column to the LEFT! it would seem that would mean that `0 + (r =1)` was evaluating to -1, which seems strange.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: in VBA `True` equals to `-1` and `False` to `0`. Try `MsgBox CInt(True)`

Comment: @simoco Consider posting this as an **answer** as it may be of interest to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3(v=vs.90).aspx):

> When `Visual Basic` converts numeric data type values to `Boolean`, `0` becomes `False` and all other values become `True`. When `Visual Basic` converts `Boolean` values to numeric types, `False` becomes `0` and `True` becomes `-1`.

You can easily check it using following test:

```
MsgBox CInt(True)  ' returns -1
MsgBox CInt(False) ' returns 0
```

Assuming that, you can change your code to:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0 - (r = 1)).Select
```

Also I suggest you to read this post: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: do you have a link that explains why `true` evaluates to 1 in an excel formula but -1 in vba?

Comment: I already gave you the link in my answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  VBA is not Excel language. It is independend programming language that was used in office programs (and many others) and has its own features like `True=-1`. There is no any explanation why Excel uses `1` and VBA `-1`. It's just by design. Excel developers team desided `True=1` and VBA developers team desided `True=-1`

Comment: also, as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae382yt8(v=vs.90).aspx): _You should never write code that relies on equivalent numeric values for True and False. Whenever possible, you should restrict usage of Boolean variables to the logical values for which they are designed. If you must mix Boolean and numeric values, make sure that you understand the conversion method that you select_. E.g. if you'd work with excel through VBA, then `CInt(True)` returns `-1`. However in VB.NET coversion `ToInt32(True)` returns `+1`. You can use `Offset(0, 0 + IIF(r = 1,1,0)).Select`